# Javascript/jQuery encoding for special characters when using val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with special characters like &, ä, etc. and their corresponding HTML encoded writing like `&amp;`, `&auml;` etc.

- When they are used in the value tag of input fields, the browser decodes it automatically, no problem at all.
- When using jQuerys val() function, the browser has no chance to evaluate the content correctly

  ```
  $("button").click(function(){
      $("#test").val("&amp;");
  });
  ```

Any idea?

Comment: There is actually no encoding or decoding going on when you use the `val` method. If you have an initial value in the field, it's decoded when the HTML is parsed, not when the value is read. Why would you need to use HTML encoded values here in the first place?

Comment: Because I want to enter data in the input fields dynamically (based on a drop down select box, where you select the data set). And the data inserted here has to be XSS safe.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Using some arbitrary encoding doesn't make the code more safe but less, you should encode the value properly for how it's going to be used. If you put the text in a string literal, it should be encoded for that purpose, not HTML encoded.

Comment: Okay, I see. Do you have an example? It needs to be in an input field, because it should be possible to change the text afterwards.

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info

Answer (score 34):

You can use this age-old entity decoding trick:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#test").val($("<div>").html("&amp;").text());
});
```

> **Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/XegGy/**

It creates a temporary `<div>` element, sets its HTML to `&amp;` and then gets the text value, which will be `&`.

Answer (score 5):

Try [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function:

```
$("#test").html("&amp;");
```