# Setting an Input Field Value to Foreign Characters

Tags: jquery, character-encoding

If i specify an input field value like this:

```
 <input type="text" id="requiredField" value="Lait &#233;cr&#233;m&#233;"/>
```

The text will show in the input as: Lait écrémé, howvever if I do this with jQuery.val()...

```
$("#requiredField").val("Lait &#233;cr&#233;m&#233;");
```

It will not show correctly...

Any suggestions for this problem? Or could this be a jQuery bug? Is there a command to convert this?

Note: the page is utf8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792362/javascript-jquery-encoding-for-special-characters-when-using-val

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of those html entities is that you can avoid using unicode encoding. If you are using uncode encoding such as utf-8 properly, they are pointless.

Anyways, `val` doesn't automatically decode them, it just takes the literal value. You can use this trick to get them decoded:

```
$("#requiredField").val($("<div>").html("Lait &#233;cr&#233;m&#233;").text())
```

Comment: answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792362/javascript-jquery-encoding-for-special-characters-when-using-val

Comment: @RabNawaz good find, we can close as duplicate. Though I still like to point out that html entities are useless if you are using unicode encoding so I am keeping my answer.