# jQuery encoding for special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working on a web application in ASP.NET MVC
I have following parts of code in my HTML:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('.foo').click(function () {
        var fooName = $("#fooName").val();
        this.href = this.href.replace("xxx", fooName);
    });
});
```

and:

```
<input type="text" value="@ViewBag.fooName" name="fooName" id="fooName" autocomplete="on" />
```

and:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Action", "ActionName", new { someObject = item.ID, fooName="xxx"}, new { @class = "foo" })
```

it works fine if there are no special characters (like #) in the textBox input. Otherwise it messes it up. I need those special characters though. I have found a tip:
[Javascript/jQuery encoding for special characters when using val()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792362/javascript-jquery-encoding-for-special-characters-when-using-val)
but I don't know how to use it if I am declaring the variable fooName.
I have no idea about JavaScript, I have never seen it before. Please help me make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `encodeURIComponent()`. `encodeURIComponent()` escapes all characters except the following: alphabetic, decimal digits, - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's exactly what I needed

Comment: @xxintxx you are welcome. please accept my answer to help other person that have the same question.